# What is the license for the learning model?

Tags: tensorflow

I am creating an application using tensorflow's object detection API.

At that time, I am doing transitional learning based on the following model.
ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017.tar.gz

I understood that tensorflow's license is Apache License 2.0,
For the model of ssd mobilenet, I could not find a description about licensing.

Regarding the license of this model,
Would you please let me know if you know it?

Thank you.

Comment: To best of knowledge these models are for free and don't come with any licensing restrictions